# What is the fastest algorithm for multiplying one given number with many others?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

When multiplying two numbers with each other, which are $n$-bit numbers, there are several algorithms like the one of Karatsuba ($O(n^{\log_2 3})$) and a new one doing it even better (Harvey - Van der Hoeven) with a complexity of $O(n \cdot \log n)$, which is much better, of course.

My question is now, if we a given a number $x$ and $m$ numbers $y_1, \ldots, y_m$, is there a faster algorithm than $O(m \cdot f(n))$, where $f(n)$ is the complexity of the fastest multiplication algorithm for just two numbers?

Comment: "and a new one"? which one? what is your unit of computation? what is $n$?

Comment: I assume the "new one" refers to the Harvey–Van der Hoeven algorithm.

Comment: I adapted the question accordingly. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: I don't know your exact algorithmic cost model, but [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/integer-multiplication-when-one-integer-is-fixed) should be relevant.

Comment: David Harvey. Joris van der Hoeven. "Integer multiplication in time $O(n\log n)$." Ann. of Math. (2) 193 (2) 563 - 617, March 2021. https://doi.org/10.4007/annals.2021.193.2.4 https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematics/volume-193/issue-2/Integer-multiplication-in-time-Onmathrmlog-n/10.4007/annals.2021.193.2.4.short

Comment: @GerryMyerson many thanks for your input. However, my question is whether we can speed things up by building many products together.

Comment: I know what your question is, tobias. But don't you think some users might find it helpful to know how the two-number case works, before they start to think about the $m+1$-number case?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure, can we find a shortcut by varying their method?

Comment: I don't know, but if I were trying to find an answer, that's the first thing I'd try to do.

Comment: This is equivalent to multiplying an $n$ and $m>n$ bit numbers, and you're looking for something better than $O(m\log n)$. I don't believe it's possible, but you can try to look at what GMP does in this case